# Import custom data to GA, custom dimension data not shown

Tags: google-analytics, data-import, custom-dimensions

I imported csv data to GA by custom Dataset:
[Dataset config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rs9kS.png)

And this is the data imported:

```
ga:browser,ga:dimension1,ga:dimension2,ga:dimension3
Mobile Safari,/app/tabs/products/4571136832125,13.1,27.91.141.47
Chrome Mobile,/tutorial,67.0.3396.87,49.96.37.242
Mobile Safari,/app/tabs/shop/flyers/00116560001,12.1,101.140.190.73
Mobile Safari,/app/tabs/products/search/freeword/list,13.1,113.148.129.44
Chrome Mobile,/app/tabs/account,80.0.3987.117,153.137.184.38
Mobile Safari,/app/tabs/products/search/freeword/list,13.1,114.148.42.25
Mobile Safari,/app/tabs/shop/flyers/00116560101,13.1,116.81.5.167
```

[And I created a custom report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOBYE.png)

[But just browser metric shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9YQS.png)

while [custom dimensions data not displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fx3KP.png)

Comment: Try to use Sessions instead Bounce Rate or click on main dimension instead add secondary dimension.

Comment: Hi @MichelePisani, thanks for you comment. I try using Sessions instead of Bounce Rate, but the result is similar.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind Custom Data import is to enable extending GA data with your own columns. For instance, you might set some custom labels to a combination of Browser and Operating System. To do that in your import columns for `Browser` and `Operating System` have match existing data.

- In your case there are two issues:
- values for `ga:browser` doesn't match existing reporting values.

there are multiple rows for browser despite browser set as a key field for import.
Consider looking carefully through the [example](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3191417?hl=en&ref_topic=6231226) provided in the docs